# Subtract two rows and insert into a third row

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to sum up two rows. I have a table1 as the below:

| MEASURES | APR | MAY | JUN | JUL |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Measure 1 | 61 | 67 | 79 | 62 |
| Measure 2 | 56 | 75 | 52 | 70 |

I need to get the difference of the two rows as the below:

| MEASURES | APR | MAY | JUN | JUL |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Total | -5 | 8 | -27 | 8 |

I tried using the below statement:

```
SELECT TOP(1)
   'DEFICIT' AS [MEASURES]
    APR - lag(APR, 1, 0) OVER (ORDER BY [MEASURES]) AS APR
   ,MAY - lag(MAY, 1, 0) OVER (ORDER BY [MEASURES]) AS MAY
   ,JUN - lag(JUN, 1, 0) OVER (ORDER BY [MEASURES]) AS JUN
   ,JUL - lag(JUL, 1, 0) OVER (ORDER BY [MEASURES]) AS JUL
   FROM table1
   ORDER BY [MEASURES] DESC;
```

But doesn't result correctly. I am not sure how to get the difference.
Can you please point me to some solution. Thanks in advance.

Comment: your result is a sum not a difference, so you never will get your result that way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just conditionally sum the columns

```
SELECT 'Total'
    , SUM(CASE WHEN MEASURES = 'Measure 2' THEN -1 ELSE 1 END * APR) APR
    , SUM(CASE WHEN MEASURES = 'Measure 2' THEN -1 ELSE 1 END * MAY) MAY
    , SUM(CASE WHEN MEASURES = 'Measure 2' THEN -1 ELSE 1 END * JUN) JUN
    , SUM(CASE WHEN MEASURES = 'Measure 2' THEN -1 ELSE 1 END * JUL) JUL
FROM table1;
```

Answer (score -1):

```
select 'Total' as Measure, sum(APR) as APR,sum(MAY) as MAY,sum(JUNE) as JUNE,sum(JULY) as JULY
from table1;
```

Comment: Hmmm... seems identical to my answer?

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.